# SQLite select where empty?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, isnullorempty

In SQLite, how can I select records where `some_column` is empty?
Empty counts as both `NULL` and `""`.

Comment: It helps if you phrase questions as questions. What are we supposed to answer?

Answer (score 323, accepted):

There are several ways, like:

```
where some_column is null or some_column = ''
```

or

```
where ifnull(some_column, '') = ''
```

or

```
where coalesce(some_column, '') = ''
```

of

```
where ifnull(length(some_column), 0) = 0
```

Comment: What are the advantages of each solution?

Comment: @Pacerier: There may be some difference in performance, but other than that it's just a matter of style.

Comment: @Guffa I mean of course the performance.. This is database isn't it? optimization is important in dbs. a little performance gain is **alot**

Comment: length(some_column) should be avoided, since this may calculate the length on the fly - AFAIK current SQLite does for columns with text affinity. Other than that, you are at the mercy of the optimizer - though I would expect them to be identical. You could verify that by using EXPLAIN.

Comment: @peterchen: Yes, it depends on what the optimiser does. I included the `length` example because it might actually be faster in some situation, as comparing numbers is simpler than comparing strings. If the performance for that is a concern, you should of course check what it does.

Answer (score 32):

It looks like you can simply do:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE some_column IS NULL OR some_column = '';
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (id int, some_column varchar(10));

INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (1, NULL);
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (2, '');
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (3, 'test');
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (4, 'another test');
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (5, NULL);
```

Result:

```
SELECT id FROM your_table WHERE some_column IS NULL OR some_column = '';

id        
----------
1         
2         
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean

```
select x
from some_table
where some_column is null or some_column = ''
```

but I can't tell since you didn't really ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following:

```
int counter = 0;
String sql = "SELECT projectName,Owner " + "FROM Project WHERE Owner= ?";
PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
prep.setString(1, "");
ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    counter++;
}
System.out.println(counter);
```

This will give you the no of rows where the column value is null or blank.