# Deal with null value in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, null

I want to insert a zero in a record that contains a null value by updating that table. I have used the following code but to no avail.

```
Statement statementXIV = db.createStatement("UPDATE Temp54 SET bal53 = '0' WHERE balan = NULL ");
                    statementXIV.prepare();
                    statementXIV.execute();       
                    statementXIV.close();
```

What is the right way to use a `null` in a `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using:

```
UPDATE Temp54 SET bal53 = '0' WHERE balan IS NULL OR balan = ''
```

Also, see this link, [SQLite select where empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620828/sqlite-select-where-empty).  The accepted answer gives a variety of methods which is always good to know.