# Unable to select rows with blank cells in Pandas Dataframe using SQLite

Tags: python, dataframe, sqlite

Querying a pandas data frame using SQLite, I am wanting to select all rows that have a country cell entry of ''. So no characters in the cell. However, when I run the SQLite query I am getting no rows returned. Still new to Python.

**Data frame structure:**

- Policy:    object
- Country:             object
- State:               object

**Data frame example:**

| Policy | Country | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | NY |
| 2 |  | CA |
| 3 | US | FL |

**SQLite select:**

```
sqlcode = '''
Select
  [Policy],
  [Country],
  [State]
From
  sqldf
Where
  Country = ''
'''

check = psl.sqldf(sqlcode,locals())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the empty values on your column [Country] are actually `NULL` values. If you are trying to actually do a filter by empty values:

For example using:

```
sqlcode = '''
Select
  [Policy Reference],
  [Country],
  [State]
From
  sqldf
Where
  Country is null or Country = ''
'''
```

you can refer to this topic on stackoverflow -> [SQLite select where empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620828/sqlite-select-where-empty)